# Dashboard: providing user feedback by changing button label

Tags: javascript, dashboard, dashcode

What I want is to provide user feedback about operation status through button label.
Initially the button says "save", once clicked I want to change the label to "saving..." enter another function and once the function returns change the label to "saved" then pause 2 seconds and set the label again to initial "save" value.

Here is the code:

```
function myClickHandler(event)
{   
    document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.color = "saving...";
    functionx ()
    document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.color = "saved";
    sleep (5000);
    document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.color = "save";
}
```

The problem is that for some reason only the last `document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.color = "save";` is actually visible on canvas because the canvas or button are rendered only once I exit from `myClickHandler` function.
Any hint?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work better.  I'm pretty sure setTimeout is non-blocking.

```
function myClickHandler(event) {
    updateLabel("saving...");
    setTimeout("performFunctionX()", 250);
}

function performFunctionX() {
    functionx;()
    updateLabel("saved");
    setTimeout("updateLabel('save')", 5000);
}

function updateLabel(labelText) {
    document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.color = labelText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (so far, I have to test it yet on the productive widget), I just had to use
document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.innerText = labelText;
instead of
document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.color = labelText;
The .color was a typo from my side, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it does work, tested now. Sad that I do not understand exactly why does it work, but I guess this will come by time.
Thanks again
Zsolt

Comment: Your original code is blocking the browser and not allowing it to render.  All your calls are synchronous.  However, setTimeout() is asynchronous, so rendering can be performed while it executes.